# Geodjango: OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: gdal, geodjango, osgeo

**Error**

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python\installation files\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "e:\python\installation files\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()

  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "e:\python\installation files\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\options.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\widgets.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\WIN8\Envs\my_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 52, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "e:\python\installation files\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

I have followed the [geodjango documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows) for windows. I have installed OSGeo4W 64bit installer and also set the environment variables as said in the documentation.

**settings.py** file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.gis',
]
```

and

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

OSGeo4W is successfully installed and path variables are set correctly as I can access gdal from cmd. Screenshot included.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu7rC.png)

Comment: I am getting the same error after upgrading django 2.2 to 3.4. How to solve this issue?